# How do i reformat my heatmap using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Below I have the following code that generates a heatmap that plots each point as a block. But I want to switch the appearence to more traditional heatmaps. It currently looks like [image: this]

but I want to make it appear like [image]

though since the dataset is all 0 it would be one color but this is for future data. Below I have attached the code that generates the first heatmap, I need to rewrite the code to change its appearence into the second one. I couldnt find the code on the matplotlib examples

import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
try:
    temp = [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

    temp = np.array(temp)
    column = ["2-12","2-12","2-12","2-12", "2-13", "2-13","2-13","2-13","2-14","2-14","2-14","2-14", "2-15", "2-15", "2-15", "2-15", "2-16","2-16","2-16","2-16", "2-17", "2-17", "2-17", "2-17", "2-18","2-18","2-18","2-18","2-19","2-19","2-19","2-19", "2-20","2-20","2-20","2-20", "2-21", "2-21", "2-21", "2-21","2-22","2-22","2-22","2-22"]
    nodes = ["0-3", "4-7", "8-11", "22-15", "26-19", "20-23", "24-27", "28-31", "32-35", "36-39"]


    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    im = ax.imshow(temp)

    # We want to show all ticks...
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(column)))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(nodes)))
    # ... and label them with the respective list entries
    ax.set_xticklabels(column)
    ax.set_yticklabels(nodes)

    # Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
             rotation_mode="anchor")

    # Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.
    for i in range(len(nodes)):
        for j in range(len(column)):
            text = ax.text(j, i, temp[i, j],
                           ha="center", va="center", color="w")

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: There isn't really any difference between the two, right? Is it that you want to remove the ticklabels?

Comment: No when filled with data it looks like the following: https://imgur.com/a/4bKTMar

Comment: I do have problems to understand how you would like it to look instead. Obviously the data in the colorful image is much denser and continuous, so it will never look exactly like that picture.

Comment: The color scheme and the scale on the side is mainly what I'm going for

Comment: The scale on the side is `fig.colorbar(im)`. The color scheme is called `jet` and is in general not recommended. What you see is called `viridis` and is a more natural choice. For all colormaps see https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html